# PCI Compliance with Paid Memberships Pro and Stripe

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I'm posting this on multiple platforms because I understand that there may be multiple options. I just want to get as much feedback as possible.
So I have a website up with WordPress through Hostgator. My WordPress site has an option where people can sign up for paid subscriptions filling out payment forms generated by the plugin: Paid Memberships Pro. I have PMPro integrated with my Stripe account, and the payment page is protected by the SSL: Let's Encrypt. The page is also TSL 1.3. So I am almost 100 percent confident that I'm PCI compliant.
The reason I'm posting on here, however, is that a colleague is concerned that my payment forms are on my site, not Stripe. So there's concern over security in that respect. So my question: Is there a way to have the payment forms on the Stripe site instead of my site in a way to still be able to use Paid Memberships Pro? If not, am I safe as is or do I have to forget about Paid Memberships Pro and try to do everything through Stripe? If I have to do everything through Stripe, how do I get Stripe to have my website let my user generate a username and password for my site after paying?
If I'm asking anything that could be answered easily through a tutorial of some sorts, forgive me and give me a reference to that sort. I just want to make sure I'm doing everything correctly. So thanks everybody in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: the payment form is on my site but the sensitive info entered on that form goes directly to Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

You should review the [PCI Compliance guide](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance) and reach out for support from the plugin provider to understand how their plugin works. All card information should be collected securely with [Stripe.js & Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js). While this appears to the customer as though it is "on your site" it is actually inside a Stripe-hosted iframe for exactly this reason.

You can also use redirect-based products like [Checkout](https://stripe.com/payments/checkout) to [set up subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout), but I don't know if this is supported by your plugin.